# Best way to deploy a python command line script?

Tags: python, shell, deployment, terminal, containers

I've written a linux file transfer script in python that takes multiple command line/terminal arguments. It works on my development machine, but when I tried to run it on my companies systems I get several errors from not having the same version of python or all of the libraries installed.

An hour of googling has opened my beginner eyes to the world of deployment methods, containers, virtualization, freezing, etc. Short of becoming a docker expert overnight, what would be the simplest way to get this script running anywhere?

Comment: One of the better ways is running python script as systemd service.

Comment: Look into `virtualenv` for this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid virtualization/Docker (which seems to be OK to me) you may at least want to use [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module with frozen dependencies. You may easily deploy directly from source (no need of packaging) with [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) providing appropriate [`setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) file.

I'm using this approach for a long time with many many deployments on many servers and many different environments. There are few things to consider:

- Your code need to be compatible with Python available on target machine. I'm using mostly Debian, so my code has to be often backwards compatible (Debian is quite conservative).
- You need to make sure that versions of dependencies installed during deployment will work with your script. Simplest thing is to freeze module versions in `setup.py`, but I don't do this as a general rule - newer library versions usually work.
- Separate `venv` for each project (usually for each repository) to avoid conflicts. In early days of my adventure wit hPython I used one uber-virtualenv, but it was a complete mess. Today it's not a big deal to use few more megabytes to separate environments.
- Automatize deployment (Ansible, Chef whatever) to do the boring stuff and never forget about important stuff. I'm using Ansible to do rarily repeated stuff like system configuration (packages, libraries, configuration files) and Jenkins for recurring stuff like project deployment (as simple as running `pip` in appropriate virtual environment).
- For daemon-like scripts (web servers, watchdogs etc.) I'm using [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) which works very well not only with Python scripts.

Comment: Thank you. I found a venv tutorial here, https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ , the only part I seem to still not understand is once you have the virtual environment set up how would you 'export' that into a single file that can be called from the terminal or would you wrap everything in a bash script?

Comment: You don't export virtualenv, you just use it. You can activate virtual env to run scripts or you can execute scripts using venv's Python (located under `bin/python`) by using full path to interpreter (`/my/path/to/venv/bin/python myscript.py`). This approach is very safe and doesn't require you to play with shebang.